# FileSystem not found exception when using getResources

Tags: java, resources

I am very lost with the concept of getResources.

I have put a simple text file in a bin folder which I would like to access as a resource so I can then build and deploy. However when I try to run the jar file I get a file not found error which I think is down to how I am accessing the resource. How can I use it?

```
public class Iterator {
    static ArrayList<String> myFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    static URL filename= Iterator.class.getResource("/Files/FilesLogged.txt");
    static String folderName;
    static Path p;

    public Iterator() { }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException, SQLException, ParseException, URISyntaxException, BackingStoreException {       
                       
        Preferences userPrefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(TBB_SQLBuilder.class);

        p = Paths.get(filename.toURI());
        //This iterates through each of the files in the specified folder and copies them to a log. 
        //It also checks to see if that file has been read already so that it isn't re-inputted into the database if run again               
        //Loop through the ArrayList with the full path names of each folder in the outer loop
        for (String line : Files.readAllLines(p)){
            myFiles.add(line);
        }   
    }
}
```

The error I get

```
Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.FileSystemNotFoundException
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getFileSystem(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:171)
at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.getPath(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:157)
at java.nio.file.Paths.get(Paths.java:143)
at Overview.Iterator.main(Iterator.java:46)
```

**Edit with @BorisTheSpiders' answer:

```
public class Iterator {
    static ArrayList<String> myFiles = new ArrayList<String>();
    
    static URL filename= Iterator.class.getResource("/Files/FilesLogged.txt");
    static String folderName;
    static Path p;
    public Iterator() {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, SAXException, TikaException, SQLException, ParseException, URISyntaxException, BackingStoreException {       
                       
        Preferences userPrefs = Preferences.userNodeForPackage(TBB_SQLBuilder.class);
        InputStream in = filename.openStream( );
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( in ) );
             p = Paths.get(filename.toURI());
            //This iterates through each of the files in the specified folder and copies them to a log. 
            //It also checks to see if that file has been read already so that it isn't re-inputted into the database if run again               
            //Loop through the ArrayList with the full path names of each folder in the outer loop
            for (String line : Files.readAllLines(p)){
                myFiles.add(line);
            }
```

but I'm not really sure how I then use the reader to provide a `Paths.get` with a `uri`. I think I'm probably not understanding something fundamental here...

Comment: Show us your file-system.

Comment: You do not get a `FileNotFoundException`, you get a `FileSystemNotFoundException`! This is a completely other issue. See @BoristheSpider's comment.

Comment: `class.getResource` returns an **opaque URI** to a path _inside_ the Jar. You **cannot** do what you want. You need to use [`Class.getResourceAsStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResourceAsStream(java.lang.String)) directly. Or, alternatively, [`URL.openStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream()).

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose the issue is obvious, see my comment. No further information is required.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Oh! Didn't really look at it. Good find.

Comment: Resources are in JAR files, not the file system, and they are not files.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments, the file in question cannot be found in the file system.

As a suggestion, try replacing

```
static URL filename= Iterator.class.getResource("/Files/FilesLogged.txt");
```

with

```
static InputStream is = Iterator.class.getResourceAsStream("/Files/FilesLogged.txt");
```

and the block where the file is read with the following:

```
try (Scanner scanner = new Scanner(is)) {
   while(scanner.hasNextLine()){
        String line = scanner.nextLine();
        myFiles.add(line);
    }
}
```